# Sendmail awk output. List of mysql backups

Tags: bash, shell, awk, echo, sendmail

I'm using this script to get the list of files and their size from our backups directory. It's working fine but what I would like to do is to email the results to dbadistro@abc.com. We use sendmail in our servers. Please help. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HEADER="\nLIST OF BACKUPS IN $(hostname):/backups/$1/$2:\n"
echo -e $HEADER
ls -lth "/backups/$1/$2" | awk 'BEGIN {print "FILE_NAME\t\t\tDATE\t\tSIZE\n--------------------------------------------------------"} NR>1 {printf "%s\t\t%s-%s %s\t%s\n",$9,$6,$7,$8,$5}'
```

Script Output sample:

```
LIST OF BACKUPS IN server1:/backups/mysql/daily:

FILE_NAME                    DATE          SIZE
--------------------------------------------------------

meb.20140108-030003.img     Jan-08 19:35    90G
meb.20140107-030003.img     Jan-07 19:35    87G
meb.20140106-030003.img     Jan-06 19:35    99G
meb.20140105-030003.img     Jan-05 19:35    98G
```

I would like to get this output emailed to me in a daily basis. Please help.

Comment: What do you need help with? Can you show the sendmail commands you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Run your script from `cron`. Use `MAILTO=` in `crontab` to specify where to email its output.

see `mail -S5 controntab` and `man crontab`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bash script. Uses local mail agent.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

out='/tmp/some_random_file_or_something'

mutt -e 'my_hdr From:god@backup.com' -s "[BACKUPS ARE READY! ;)] $(date)." your@email.com -c yourhome@email.com < $out

rm -f $out
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below command in cronjob. For example, send mail at 5am daily

```
0 5 * * * bash /FULL_PATH/yourscript.sh
```

normally if your system has sendmail, it should support `mailx` command, which is easier.

$ cat yourscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
HEADER="\nLIST OF BACKUPS IN $(hostname):/backups/$1/$2:\n"
echo -e $HEADER
ls -lth "/backups/$1/$2" | awk 'BEGIN {print "FILE_NAME\t\t\tDATE\t\tSIZE\n--------------------------------------------------------"} NR>1 {printf "%s\t\t%s-%s %s\t%s\n",$9,$6,$7,$8,$5}' > temp
cat temp|mailx -s "backup report on `date`" dbadistro@abc.com
```